# How to connect remix ide to geth running on localhost?

Tags: remix

Previously, according to tutorials, remix IDE had cube icon to connect to geth on localhost. Now the icon is gone and its not clear if the function is still there. Is it possible? How? I take remix here: https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/blob/gh-pages/remix-7daae65.zip

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality has now been moved to `Run` -> `Environment` -> `Web3 Provider`:

[image]

In the popup I had to enter `http://127.0.0.1:8545`, it did not work with the default `http://localhost:8545`. I am connecting to a local geth node on macOS. Make sure to enable RPC and give access to remix via:

```
geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "https://remix.ethereum.org" console
```

Comment: Yes, and I get known JSON "" error.

Comment: What OS are you on and which version of geth are you using? Then pls double-check that you 1) started geth with the correct parameters as I indicated, 2) entered the right address of your node in the popup of remix (try also the default `http://localhost:8545`).

Comment: Here is screenshot of my problem: https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/issues/620, can't post another answer here, not enough carma :(

Comment: did you try with `--rpccorsdomain "https://remix.ethereum.org"` instead of `--rpccorsdomain "*"` as in the screenshot? If that persists it might be a windows specific issue. Check if you can connect from e.g. nodeJS and file an issue for geth if it persists.

Comment: The same story with --rpccorsdomain "https://remix.ethereum.org"

Comment: HI! The issue resolved, see details in the github issue.

Comment: but I explicitely wrote `https` in the corsdomain - does that work then?

Comment: the reason was missing --rpc flag

Comment: Yeah but that's written in my answer, just had to copy-paste that ;-) happy that it's working for you!

Comment: Make sure you are not loading `remix.ethereum.org` from non-https (yes, they have non-https as well). Otherwise adjust your `--rpccorsdomain` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to improve Sebastian's answer -- the location of this setting has changed to:

- ***Run*** → ***Environment*** → ***Web3 Provider***
  (at top right)

[image: Web3 Provider]